# I get "no such method" when using ES6 static functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a "utils" class with static functions in it for a project I work on in react native.

I read about how to make static functions in a StackOverFlow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893591/es6-modules-export-single-class-of-static-methods-or-multiple-individual-method%20question), but for some odd reason it ain't working for me.

```
//utils.js
'use strict'

export default {
  textFormat(args) {
      var s = args[0];
      for (var i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++) {
          var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");
          s = s.replace(reg, args[i + 1]);
      }
      return s;
  }
}


//main file
import * as Utils from './utils/utils';
/**
/...
**/
var text = Utils.textFormat(rowData.text, "<Text style={{color:'blue'}}>Hey there</Text>");
```

But I keep getting this error 'Utils.textFormat is not a function', what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try `import Utils from './utils/utils'`? That should conform with your current definition.

Comment: You don't have named export, but export a single object.

Comment: @bebraw doing this just gives me textFormat is not defined error.

Comment: @zerkms thank you, I'm not sure I understand that. What should I change?

Comment: If you want to retain the import as is, a named export would be the way to go then, yeah. So do plain `export` for the function instead of `export default`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good thing you got things working, but I'd just like to add a solution that more closely resembles what you were originally trying to do, and heeds the points made in [the SO question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893591/es6-modules-export-single-class-of-static-methods-or-multiple-individual-method%20question).

There is just no need to use `class` to export bunch of static methods. I don't see how it would add functionality, ease of use or clarity to the code. Quite the contrary actually, the syntax looks more verbose than exporting plain old ES5 style objects and even more so when we bring ES6+ sweetness to the mix.

---

Your original example of the utils module works just fine. The problem is in the *import*.

As you are just exporting one default object, the correct way to import it would be

```
import Utils from './utils/utils';
```

No brackets, no asterisks, just a name for the imported default object, which can then be used like `var text = Utils.textFormat(...)`.

We can go further, though. By ditching the whole *"export one default object"* approach, we can use the full power of the module system.

*utils.js:*

```
'use strict'

function textFormat(args) {
      var s = args[0];
      ...
      return s;
}

const someOtherUtility = str => str + ' works!';

export { textFormat, someOtherUtility };
```

Now the exported functions can be used like this

```
import * as Utils from './utils/utils';

var text = Utils.textFormat(rowData.text, "<Text style={{color:'blue'}}>Hey there</Text>");
```

*Or* like this

```
import {textFormat} from './utils/utils';

var text = textFormat(rowData.text, "<Text style={{color:'blue'}}>Hey there</Text>");
```

Whichever you prefer.

Comment: I understand my mistake now, thank you for your answer, I deleted mine

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the two approaches laid out in the linked question, which doesn't work. It should either be

```
// utils.js
export default {
  textFormat(args) {
    var s = args[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++) {
      var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");
      s = s.replace(reg, args[i + 1]);
    }
    return s;
  }
}
```

```
// main file
import Utils from './utils/utils';
…
var text = Utils.textFormat(rowData.text, "<Text style={{color:'blue'}}>Hey there</Text>");
```

or

```
// utils.js
export function textFormat(args) {
  var s = args[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++) {
    var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");
    s = s.replace(reg, args[i + 1]);
  }
  return s;
}
```

```
// main file
import * as Utils from './utils/utils';
…
var text = Utils.textFormat(rowData.text, "<Text style={{color:'blue'}}>Hey there</Text>");
```

(the latter is preferable)

Comment: I used your answer? Is it best way or it's better to define a class in `utils.js`?

Comment: @b24 No, it's an awful idea to use `class` syntax only to define static methods.