# import all in typescript does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I don't know if I am stupid, but, I have installed web-request module:

```
npm install web-request
```

it is installed, it is present in node modules.
I try to use it:

```
import * as WebRequest from 'web-request';
export class MyHttp {

public static getUrl() {

console.log('hello');
  WebRequest.get('http://www.google.com/').then(()=> {
     console.log('success'); 
});

}
 }
```

Then I use it in the test:

```
import {MyHttp} from '../../../services/MyHttp';

describe('Request', () => {

  fit('should be successful', () => {
   MyHttp.getUrl();
   setTimeout(()=> {
   expect(true).toBe(true);
},5000);

 });

 });
```

The console output is:

```
hello
```

I cannot see 'success' output at all.

The typings is ok, I am able to enter web-request\index.d.ts, that looks fine.

What am I doing wrong ? :(

Comment: Your test runner is exiting immediately because it's not aware that you are running async behavior. Read the jasmine docs for how to write an async test function.

Comment: Don't create classes consisting of only static methods, and don't export them: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572

Comment: Have you tried adding a `catch` error handler to the promise?

Comment: Even when I use Promise then in the test it wont success either. I use static, so the tests are clear, I've read a rule, no new keyword in tests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the tests needs a callback to be called in order for the test runner to know that it finished and that it is Async. Here is an example base on your code. You can read about jasmine for instance [here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/upgrading.html).

```
import * as WebRequest from 'web-request';
export class MyHttp {
    public static async getUrl() {
        console.log('hello');
        await WebRequest.get('http://www.google.com/')
        console.log('success'); 
    }   
}
it('should be successful', () => {
    MyHttp.getUrl();
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

edit: If you look in the docs of [web-request](https://github.com/davetemplin/web-request) it seems that they use await. There is no need for `then` after the function call. This pauses execution until the promise is resolved and gives you the value in the return object. While not suitable for all things it can make sense for testing.

Comment: Yep, I tried that callback , it does not work either

Comment: I've changes my answer a bit.

Comment: function should be async