# How can I import a namespace?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a JavaScript file which contains the following:

```js
const api = {
  call(type, url, data) {
    console.log(type + "bar");
  },

  get(url, query) {
    this.call("foo");
  }
}
```

I'm wanting to be able to call `api.get()` across multiple different files where necessary, but I'm having trouble importing this.

1. Loading the file alone through `import` gives me a ReferenceError when I attempt to access the `api` variable:

   ```
   import "services/api.js";
   console.log(api);
   ```

   > Uncaught ReferenceError: api is not defined
2. Giving the import a name (of `api`) returns an Object, but it has no inner methods:

   ```
   import api from "../../services/api.js";
   console.log(api);
   console.log(api.get);
   ```

   > Object {}
   >   undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `api.js` is not exporting anything. You should rewrite it to export every of these functions:

```
export function call(type, url, data) {
    console.log(type + "bar");
}
export function get(url, query) {
    call("foo");
}
```

(which is much better than default-exporting an `api` object literal)

and then you can use it like

```
import * as api from "../../services/api.js";
console.log(api);
console.log(api.get);
```

Comment: Thanks. You say it's much better to do it this way, but why is this so?

Comment: Neater, more maintainable syntax and more flexibility for importing.

Comment: That makes sense, this way I'm not having to import functions which aren't required. Perfect!

Answer (score 3):

First you have to export it, as such:

```
const api = {
  call(type, url, data) {
    console.log(type + "bar");
  },

  get(url, query) {
    this.call("foo");
  }
}

export {api}
```

And then, import it:

```
import {api} from './path/to/api' // no .js
```

This approach is used when you're exporting multiple items (functions, classes, variables) from one file. If in your case `api` is the only item that you're exporting, you can use the `default` keyword and you will no longer need to use the accolades during import:

```
const api = {
  call(type, url, data) {
    console.log(type + "bar");
  },

  get(url, query) {
    this.call("foo");
  }
}

export default api
```

and

```
import api from './path/to/api'
```

Good luck!

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much. I was sure it was something very simple I was missing.

Comment: [Don't default-export object literals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572)!

Answer (score 1):

You need to export your api:

```
const api = ...

export default api;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note to this: export / import like this is ES6 module spec, be aware. For Node / CommonJS Module environments without any transpiler, it would be

```
// export
module.exports.api = api

// or
module.exports = { api: api } ...


// import
var module = require(....)
```