# can't you use recursive functions inside a method in typescript / javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, typescript, callback

I want to know whether why this seemingly OK code, does not work. 
Is there something wrong going with the callback? Can you use recursive function inside a method?

What I want to do here is, I want to call use a method inside the class `G964`, which will result something like this:

> argument: (3,5)
>   return result: [3,2,1,1]

```
export class G964 {
public static sqInRect(l: number, w: number): number[] {
    if (l === w) { return null; }

  var recur = function(arr:number[]) {
    let minusResult:number = arr.slice(-2)[0] - arr.slice(-2)[1];
    if (minusResult > 0) {
        arr.push(minusResult);
      recur(arr);
    } else {
        arr.shift();
      return arr;
    }
  }

    let testArr = [ l, w ].sort((a:number, b:number) => a-b).reverse();

  return recur(testArr);
}
}
```

Comment: You're not returning anything when `minusResult > 0`.

Comment: Plus what do you want to acheive?

Comment: This is not related to methods. That said this use of a static member is very poor style.

Comment: recur(arr);  <-- does not return

Comment: [Never export classes with only static methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29895235/1048572)!

Comment: First error i think is that you call `arr.slice(-2)` two times, that mean you don't remove 2 elements but, 4. Save result into variable and use that variable instead. Second is, that your recur function does not return value everytime. If `minusResult > 0` is true, nothing is returned.