# How to create class in one es6 module and import it in another?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have two files: `User.js` and `Login.js`. After login is successfull i want to call static `logIn` method of User class. I have strange behaviour. What am I doing wrong?

File contents [User.js](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/react-todo-app/blob/master/src/user/User.js):

```
// user/User.js

// I also tried export default class User
export class User { 
  static logIn (token) {
  }

  static logOut (token) {
  }

  static isAuthorized () {
  }
}
```

And [Login.js](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/react-todo-app/blob/master/src/login/Login.js):

```
// login/Login.js

import React from 'react';
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';
// I also tried import User from './../user/User';
// I also tried import {User} from './../user/User';
import * as User from './../user/User';

class Login extends React.Component {

  constructor (props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  responseSuccess (googleUser) {
    const idToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    User.logIn(idToken);
  }

///

}

export default Login;
```

When I use import and export this way I get this behaviour: 
[image]

So, User is an object with property `User`. This property contains all methods of class User.

Is it possible to somehow export/import class so I will get user class methods in `User` object?

Now there is only one way to use methods: `User.User.logIn()`.

Comment: When you say `import * as <NAME> from <LOC>`, if says "take all of the exports from file 'x' and collect them into one object and export that object as <NAME>". Should work if you just change your import statement to `import User from './../user/User'` since the class is your default export

Comment: Yes, it is logical explanation. I understand it. The problem it does not work... I also tried `import User from './../user/User'`, I just added one of the variants there.

Comment: The example and the screenshot show different code.

Answer (score 5):

You are using a default export, so with a namespace import (`* as User`) you'd have to use `User.default` to access the class.

Instead, use a default import:

```
import User from './../user/User';
```

---

However, your screenshot suggests that you're actually doing a named export with `export class User { … }`, not a default export. If you want to use that, you'd have to import the name:

```
import {User} from './../user/User'; // short for {User as User}
```

---

That said, you probably [shouldn't be using a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29895235/1048572) consisting of only static methods anyway. Use multiple named exports

```
export function logIn(token) {
}
export function logOut(token) {
}
export function isAuthorized() {
}
```

and then use the namespace import

```
import * as User from './../user/User';
```

to access them as `User.logIn` etc.

Comment: How should I export class? I am getting this at the moment: https://i.gyazo.com/0ef0f54c0cf87699ee638fd7c7f389f3.png. I didn't change export of the class. I tried to export class this ways: `export class User` and `export default class User`

Comment: Yes I was trying different variants and got confused.

Comment: I tried `export class User` and `import {User} from './../user/User'`. I am getting `VM16149:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: User is not defined` now.

Comment: That's weird, it should be working. Are you sure the files are loaded in the correct order (no circular references etc)?

Comment: I updated my question with links to the src of the files. Can you check file contents? Actually I didn't think it will be that hard :) I thought I just need something like `import SomeClass from './some/path'` but wow....

Comment: No idea, looks fine to me.

Comment: Well if u have 3 minutes - can you clone and write `npm install & npm start`? May be the problem is in my env...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a default export, there is no need to specify an alias via `as`.

Instead, use the following syntax to import the default export of the module:

```
import User from './../user/User';
```

More info in [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: I tried this. This doesn't work. How `export` should look like?

Comment: I added links to the github.com. Can you check file contents? Looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

import User from './../user/User';

should be enough, you dont have more exported values from that file