# cant call function from other class

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

I have 2 files.

1) accountService.js

```
export class Http {

forgotPassword(email) {
console.log(email)
  }
}
```

2) forgot-password.js

```
import {Http} from '../services/accountService'

 export class ForgotPassword {

 sendCode(email) {
    Http.forgotPassword(email)
  }
}
```

When I'm trying to call `Http.forgotPassword(email)` in `forgot-password.js` there is console error, that says `Http.forgotPassword` in not a function.

Comment: wich emacscript are you using,  trye this; module.exports =  {

forgotPassword(email) {
console.log(email)
  }
}

Comment: I'm using ecmascript 6

Comment: can be export a class¿?, with babel?

Comment: I'm transpiling this code with babel to es5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forgotPassword` method needs to be `static` if you want to call it like that;

```
static forgotPassword(email) {
    console.log(email)
}
```

Comment: Oh, it is amazing. ES6 looks like normal language

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `forgotPassword` is an instance method. You will need to do

```
export class ForgotPassword {
  constructor() {
    this.http = new Http
  }
  sendCode(email) {
    this.http.forgotPassword(email)
  }
}
```

However, if those files you've shown were the whole code, you should neither use `class`es nor export objects with methods. [Just export the functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29895235/1048572).