# How can I export static function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, static, babeljs

Basic codes main.js:

```
class Something {
  static ThisIsStaticFunction () { ... }
}

export default Something;
```

Other file xxx.js:

```
import xxx;

// I want to call `ThisIsStaticFunction()` without having to
// write `Something.ThisIsStaticFunction()` how can I achieve this?
```

I want to call `ThisIsStaticFunction()` without having to write `Something.ThisIsStaticFunction()` how can I achieve this?

Comment: Assign `Something.thisIsStaticSomething` to a `window` property (or anything else for that matter)

Comment: @Pointy Please do not assign it to `window`, global variable is usually bad idea.

Comment: @BryanChen right I wouldn't do it but the point is it's just a reference to an object.

Comment: [Don't ever make a `class` with only static methods, and don't export such an object!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572)

Comment: I think it is good for namespacing. CMIIW though.

Comment: The file itself is already a namespace, so generally static methods on classes don't come up often in JS.

Comment: Hmmm, I am not convinced yet. What if I have two functions (let say, `SampleFunction()`) in two different files (Test1.js and Test2.js). How can I import the functions from Test1.js and Test2.js without having `Test1` and `Test2` as classes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can alias the static function as a normal function

```
export const ThisIsStaticFunction = Something.ThisIsStaticFunction;
export default Something;
```

---

```
import {ThisIsStaticFunction}, Something from 'xxx';
```

---

Usually in Javascript (unlike Java) you can use plain function over static function.

```
export function ThisIsAFunction() {}

export default class Something {
    instanceMethod() {
        const result = ThisIsAFunction();
    }
}
```

---

```
import {ThisIsAFunction}, Something from 'xxx';

const foo = ThisIsAFunction();
const bar = new Something()
const biz = bar.instanceMethod();
```

Comment: I choose your answer for now. What I am concerning is: If I have so many static functions to export, then I need to assign the values one-by-one which is very tedious.

Comment: What are the reason for them to be static function? You are not writing Java

Comment: I have OOP background, and just learning ReactJS. And why there is `static` key if not to be used anyway? Additionally, I bet there is no different between exporting `static` and normal function.

Comment: @notalentgeek there is a **huge** difference between exporting a static function vs. a "method" in a class.

Comment: Can you please give me an example on how can I export `static` function and normal function?

Comment: Most of the time a plain js function is equivalent to static function. A instance method is a different story

Answer (score 0):

If we call it in the `constructor()` of the same file, there is no need to call it in another file.

app.js:

```
class Something {
  constructor()
  {
     this.number = 0;
     this.ThisIsStaticFunction(); // answer: 0
     this.ThisIsStaticFunction(); // answer: 1
     this.ThisIsStaticFunction(); // answer: 2
  }
  ThisIsStaticFunction ()
  { 
     console.log(this.number++)
  }
}
export {Something};
```

loader.js:

```
import {Something} from "./app.js";
class loader
{
    constructor()
    {
        new Something;
    }
}
new loader();
```

index.html:

```
 <script type="module" src="./loader.js"></script>
```