# Should I use ES6 Class' static methods when defining a component?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

If I have a simple component such as the one below, would it better to use static methods within my class or not? I realise this could be down to opinion but what I'm interested in is if there are architectural reasons why one way might have advantages over the other.

**Non static methods:**

```
class mainNav {
  toggleMainNav() {
    const navBtn = document.getElementById('toggle-menu');
    const navMenu = document.getElementById('main-nav');

    navBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      navMenu.classList.toggle('open');
    });
  }

  init() {
    this.toggleMainNav();
  }
}

module.exports = mainNav;
```

**To instantiate I would need to instantiate the class first like so:**

```
const mainNav = require("../js/components/mainNav/mainNav");

//Init nav
const nav = new mainNav;
nav.init();
```

**Alternatively with static methods I could do this:**

```
class mainNav {
  static toggleMainNav() {
    const navBtn = document.getElementById('toggle-menu');
    const navMenu = document.getElementById('main-nav');

    navBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      navMenu.classList.toggle('open');
    });
  }

  static init() {
    this.toggleMainNav();
  }
}

module.exports = mainNav;
```

**and instantiate:**

```
const mainNav = require("../js/components/mainNav/mainNav");

mainNav.init();
```

On the face of it using static methods in this case seems easier as I don't have to instantiate an instance of the class first.

Not coming from an OOP programming background, Is there is a reason why doing this would be considered bad practise?

Comment: Yes. You should [not have a `class` with only static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29895235/1048572). You also should not have an instance with no state and no data. In fact, it looks like all you need is a plain function.

Comment: static methods cannot use `this` when not called with an object. It will just be undefined

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings Of course that's a "problem" that all methods and functions have, not just static ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class with no data is basically a collection of static methods. This is an [antipattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ClassesWithoutOo). In this case, just exporting the function alone would suffice, like this:

```
function doSomething() { ... }
module.exports = doSomething
```

and use it like this:

```
const func = require('../path/module')
func()
```

Comment: it is quite simple you just export the function and execute it. I've updated the answer with a small example

Comment: Sorry, I realised this when I went back to my code. Thanks for updating.