# Redefine sibling functions within module scope in required file

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, module, scope

I am looking for a way to keep functions declared in module scope, export them, and allow them to be wrapped in a completely different file, and export a wrapped copy of all modules. The issue: The wrap works, but it only wraps the called function, that function is still calling the unwrapped counter-parts. Without changing the scope of the original authored modules, is there any way to tell the log version, to use only other logged version?

> colors.js

```
let green = () => 'green'
let red = () => 'red'
let purple = () => 'purple'
let colors = () => green() + red() + purple()

module.exports = {
  red,
  green,
  purple,
  colors
}
```

> colors.log.js

```
const {logWrapFns} = require('./index')
let {
  red,
  green,
  purple,
  colors
} = require('./colors')

;[red, green, purple, colors] = logWrapFns('color')([
  red,
  green,
  purple,
  colors
])

module.exports = {
  red,
  green,
  purple,
  colors
}
```

> debugFns.js

```
const {map, mapValues, get} = require('lodash')
const debug = require('debug')

const logWrapFn = (scope) => (fn, key) => (...input) => {
  const d = debug(`${scope}:${fn.name || key}`)
  d(JSON.stringify({input}))
  const possiblePromise = fn.apply(null, input)
  if (get(possiblePromise, 'then')) {
    return possiblePromise.then(output => {
      d(JSON.stringify({output}))
      return output
    })
  } else {
    d(JSON.stringify({output: possiblePromise}))
    return possiblePromise
  }
}
const logWrapFnsReturnObj = (scope) => (fns) => mapValues(fns, logWrapFn(scope))
const logWrapFnsReturnArr = (scope) => (fns) => map(fns, logWrapFn(scope))

module.exports = {
  logWrapFn,
  logWrapFns
}
```

> usage.js

```
const colors = require('./colors.log')

console.log(colors)

console.log(colors.green())
```

Only logging debug statement for `green` not the rest.

I know this is possible if I author the module with a `class` and use `static` methods, however then I have to call each method with the extra class name, which is something I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to make the original `colors` function to call something else than the original `green`/`red`/`purple` functions without modifying the original module code.

You don't need to use a `class` with static methods ([you shouldn't do that anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572)). I recommend to rewrite your module to

```
// notice this === exports
this.green = () => 'green'
this.red = () => 'red'
this.purple = () => 'purple'
this.colors = () => this.green() + this.red() + this.purple()
```

in which `colors` will call the other functions as methods of the `module.exports` object, where you can replace them by the wrapped versions:

```
// colors.log.js
const logWrap = require('./debugFns').logWrapFn('color')
const c = module.exports = require('./colors')

c.red = logWrap(c.red)
c.green = logWrap(c.green)
c.purple = logWrap(c.purple)
c.colors = logWrap(c.colors)
```

Comment: Is there a way to alter the original authored modules to support it?

Comment: Interesting use of `this`, really impressive stuff.

Comment: Added an enhancment to this via using `mapValues` in the `logWrapFns` and exporting this from `colors.log.js` `module.exports = Object.assign(c, logWrap(c))`

Comment: @ThomasReggi Actually the use of `this` is quite pointless, one should in general prefer `exports` for clarity and for being able to use it in `function`s/methods. It's only three characters longer :-)

Comment: @ThomasReggi Yeah, a loop might be sensible if you want to wrap everything by default.

Comment: Babel interpolation breaks a file with `this` https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=C4CwlgzgdA5gTgUwQOwAQF5UAoCUGB8qA5PEskQFCiRSIAmG2e6hR9l10ADgK5xcAbBI1wFivfkI7hoAYwD2A-XAgjmhTrEQpRAalSb6egzKgTBCXBSA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Creact%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=

Comment: @ThomasReggi Looks like babel repl interprets it as an ES6 module, which it is not