# Create a new static function from a class in another file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, oop

I have a class which I created static functions in it `file1`, but when i import it in another file and create a new static function it doesn't work as expected it gives me that my new static function is not a function in `file3`, How can i fix this?
Here's my code:

```
//file1

class Qbs {
  static getRfreshToken(selectors = {}, projection = {}) {
    return QuickBoooks.findOne(selectors, projection);
  }

  static updateRefreshToken(tokenId, tokenValue) {
    return QuickBoooks.update(tokenId, { $set: { refreshToken: tokenValue } });
  }
}

export default Qbs;
}


//file2
const Qbs = require('./index');

module.exports = function () {
    Qbs.prototype.sayMyName = function () {
        return 'zeyad';
    };
};


//file3
import Qbs from './file1'
console.log(Qbs.sayMyName()); //sayMyName is not a function
```

Comment: This post should be tagged with react.js, node.js and whatever else might be appropriate as this is not pure JavaScript and you may get more relevant eyes on the issue.

Comment: @daddygames Why? `static` functions are part of core JavaScript.  I also don't see react code in this question.

Comment: I added a new tag `nodejs` @daddygames

Comment: @zero298 it's not a big deal, but this whole thing is based on an understanding of NodeJS and so using the tag will make sure people who are watching that tag see it and can better help address the issue.

Comment: Uh, `Qbs.prototype.sayName = …` does not define a static function?!

Comment: Also you are never calling the function that is exported from `file2`, so it doesn't do its modifications…

Comment: [You should never use a `class` of only static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `file2` you export a function that modifies the `Qbs` prototype, but you never import `file2`, or run that function.

```
//file3
import Qbs from './file1'
import addSayMyName from './file2'

addSayMyName()
console.log(Qbs.sayMyName()); //sayMyName is not a function
```