# Static method isn't function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created class with some ratings changing. Methods in this class should be static, but I have problem with calling it.

```
class Rating {
  static changeRating ( leftRating,rightRating){
    return(leftRating+rightRating);
 }
}
```

and in another file I have

```
import { User, Team } from '../../models'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { UserInputError, ApolloError } from 'apollo-server-core';
import Joi from 'joi'
import * as Validator from '../../validation'
import * as Config from '../../config'
import * as Rating from '../../rating'
export default {
Mutation:{
 changeRating: async (root, args, { req }, info) => {
        console.log(Rating.changeRating(1255,1244))
 }
}
}
```

Then I get

```
"Rating.changeRating is not a function."
```

I want to have number, this sum is to change in future of course.

Comment: Works for me, by just copy and paste your code into the console. How can we replicate your issue? How are you importing Rating in the other file?

Comment: have you included your class into the file that is calling it?

Comment: Can you post the code from the file you're using Rating in? As well as the rest of the code from the file you defined the class in to see if you're exporting it correctly. You may be importing/exporting something incorrectly. The code you have is all correct, so it is something else.

Comment: Did you `export` `Rating`?

Comment: Yes export is problem, thanks

Comment: `import * as Rating from '../../rating'` is not how you import a class. [You shouldn't use a `class` with only static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572) however anyway. If you write `export function changeRating ( leftRating,rightRating){
    return(leftRating+rightRating);
 }`, your import syntax will work.