# How to return an object from a successful API call inside a `try` block React?

Tags: javascript

I want to return an `object` after a successful API call from another file.But everytime it call sucessfully,but the object that return is `Undefined`. Let me explain the situation clearly.

**App.js**

From `App.js` I calling `Auth.session()` which is will suppose to return a `Session()` object.

```
 try{
    Auth.session();  #data123


    console.log("data 123",Auth.session()); 

  }catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

**Auth.js**

```
export class Auth {

  static session() {

    if(token !=null){

       return Session.getSession(); //DATA 456  
                                   //Here when return to App.js,is the outcome I want
     }


    if(refreshToken != null){
       try{

        await axiosAccessClient.post(url, body)
        .then(function (response) {

            //... do something else with the response.data

            console.log(Session.getSession());  //here have the outcome I want 
            return Session.getSession(); // **DATA 678**
                                        //but here when return to App.js,it become undefined
        }).catch(function (error) {
            throw error;
        })
      } catch (e) {
            throw e
      }

    }else{
      thorw "No session"
   }
  }
}
```

**Here is my `Session` class look like**

```
export class Session {
    constructor(access_token){
        this.token=  access_token;

    }

    static getSession(){
        return new Session(
            localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
        )
    }
}
```

So I which in `App.js` ,I can get the `console.log` like this :

```
Session{access_token: .......}  //Should return this in App.js
```

I can get the above result from `if(token!= null)` **(DATA 456)** part,but in the `try` block for the API call  **(DATA 678 PART)** it return `UNDEFINED` in `App.js`.

**So my question is** ,how to return an object after successfully API call? I trying my best to address  the problem,any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Btw, `Auth.session()` will never return `undefined`, it will always return a promise. Did you mean to use `await Auth.session()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `then` when you want to work with `async`/`await`. Inside the `if (refreshToken != null)` block, you were only `return`ing from the `then` callback, but never from `Auth.session`. Use

```
export class Auth {
  static async session() {
    if (token != null) {
      return Session.getSession();
    }
    if (refreshToken != null) {
      const response = await axiosAccessClient.post(url, body);
      //... do something else with the response.data
      return Session.getSession();
    } else {
      throw new Error("No session");
    }
  }
}
```

Btw, [don't make `Auth` a `class` if `static session` is the only method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572).

Comment: then how can I know the `axios api call` is success inside `if(refreshToken != null)` ?? cause it seem like dont have the point that shown is success from the answer above

Comment: I tried your solution,in `App.js` it return a Promise instead of a `Session() ` object

Comment: @ken you know the axios call has succeeded after the `await`. (You could keep the  `try`/`catch` wrapper around it but since it only did rethrow the error and nothing else, I removed it).

Comment: @ken Yes, it must return a promise, it is an async function. (I initially forgot the `async` keyword). It must do that to be able to wait for the asynchronous result of the axios api call.