# best aproach for importing same name functions in ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I need to import same name function from two different modules in ES6. Should I rename each function with the as alias on the import or use the Reveal Module Pattern? Or perhaps there're better aproaches?

## Solution with alias

projects.module.js

```
    function init() {
      console.log("projects module initiated!");
    }

    export { init };
```

projects_steps.module.js

```
    function init() {
      console.log("project steps module initiated!");
    }

    export { init };
```

index.js

```
    import { init as projectsInit } from "./projects.module.js";
    import { init as projectStepsInit } from "./project_steps.module.js";

    projectsInit();
    projectStepsInit();
```

## Solution with Reveal Module Pattern

projects.module.js

```
var projects = (() => {
  function init() {
    console.log("projects module initiated!");
  }

  return {
    init: init
  };
})();

export { projects };
```

project_steps.module.js

```
var projectSteps = (() => {
  function init() {
    console.log("project steps module initiated!");
  }

  return {
    init: init
  };
})();
export { projectSteps };
```

index.js

```
import { projects } from "./projects.module.js";
import { projectSteps } from "./project_steps.module.js";

projects.init();
projectSteps.init();
```

Just to add, in the future will be added more functions to these modules.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the purpose of the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) in your "reveal" approach?

Comment: I vote for the reveal module pattern; semantically it seems to make sense to call init on all the individual modules. This way you can keep the function's useful name "init".

Comment: Ah... I think I'm beginning to understand. The Reveal Module pattern predates ES6 modules. You are doubling the work needlessly. If you want a prefix, then just export a constant with your functions as properties. E.g. `export const projects = { init };`

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica good point. So much easier, less overload.

Comment: Absolutely don't use the revealing module pattern in ES6. And [try to refrain from default-exporting objects with methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572). Rather, use `export function init(){ … }` in the modules, and use namespace imports *only where needed* (to disambiguate, or if you prefer it in a module with lots of other imports): `import * as projects from '/projects.module.js'; projects.init();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Revealing Module Pattern is an older pattern that predates ES6 modules. It's purpose was to hide the details of a "module" in a private function scope and to prevent the pollution of the global scope.

With ES6 modules this is completely unnecessary. Your question is really about the pros and cons of exporting individual functions versus a single interface.

Consider using the following approach instead:

projects.module.js

```
function init() {
  console.log("projects module initiated!");
}

function foo() {
}

// export an object as the default, which will act as your interface
export default { init, foo };
```

projects_steps.module.js

```
function init() {
  console.log("project steps module initiated!");
}

function foo() {
}

// you can still export individual functions where it makes sense
export function projectStepsThing() {
}

// if you don't want to export a default, then just set an object like so:
export const projectSteps = { init, foo };
```

index.js

```
import projects from "./projects.module.js";
import { projectSteps, projectStepsThing } from "./project_steps.module.js";

projects.init();
projects.foo();
projectSteps.init();
projectSteps.foo();

projectStepsThing();
```

Comment: I was told is not a good pattern to make default exports because it can make harder for manintability. Ex: change the name as the module as imported. I think  as @JDB still remembers Monica mentioned in the comments, just make export projects = { init } would solve it.

Comment: @GabrielM.Linassi Whatever floats your boat. It's a very flexible syntax.

Comment: Perfect! This was what I needed. I didn't know and ended up creating overload to my logic. Now is much neater.

Comment: Yup. I'm in the middle of a major refactor and, after initially exporting individual functions, I've really grown to prefer exporting an interface object in most cases.

Comment: by " interface object" you mean what you've just did? export { const project = { init } } ?

Comment: Yes, for lack of a better word.

Answer (score -1):

Worth noting one can also use a Class for this and add it as a singleton object within the application

```
export class SomeClass {
  constructor() { //init }
  public async doAThing() { } 
}
```

Calling file (if not using as a singleton)

```
const { SomeClass } = require('./SomeClass');
//or import SomeClass from './SomeClass';
const someClass = new SomeClass();
```