# How to import a service-like singleton-class with System.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, system.js, import-maps

I have a Singleton-Class `FooService` that is loaded via an [import-map](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps). I'd like to (a)wait for it and use it in various async functions like so:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    System: System.Module
  }
}

const module = window.System.import('@internal/foo-service')
const fooService = module.FooService

async function func1() {
  await fooService.doBar()
  .
  .
}

async function func2() {
  await fooService.doBar2()
  .
  .
}
```

But I could only get it to work like this:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    System: System.Module
  }
}

async function getfooService() {
  const module = await window.System.import('@internal/foo-service')
  return module.FooService
}

function func1() {
  getfooService().then(fooService => fooService .doBar())
  .
  .
}

function func2() {
  getfooService().then(fooService => fooService.doBar2())
  .
  .
}
```

How can I achieve this without loading it anew every time I want to use it?

Comment: Modules are not loaded anew, regardless how often you import them.

Comment: Why don't you simply write `import { FooService } from '@internal/foo-service';`?

Comment: A module already forms a singleton. No need to use a "singleton `class`".

Comment: @Bergi It is loaded via System.js because it is loaded asynchronously. Normally importing it would result in an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first guess was nearly fine. Notice that the `module` returned by `import` is a promise, so you need to use it as

```
const fooService = window.System.import('@internal/foo-service').then(module =>
  module.FooService
);

async function func1() {
  (await fooService).doBar();
//^                ^
  …
}

async function func2() {
  (await fooService).doBar2();
//^                ^
  …
}
```

Btw I would recommend to [avoid using a `FooService` "module object" (or worse, `class`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572) and instead just `export` named functions, so that you can drop the `.then(module => module.FooService)`.

Comment: Works perfectly but now Jest is tripping up with `Cannot read property 'import' of undefined` which it didn't before

Comment: @leonheess I don't think there's a `window.System` in Jest. You should probably [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that, though

Comment: I created one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65609648/jest-cannot-read-property-import-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

you could try to wrap it in IIFE, like this:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    System: System.Module
  }
}

// Wrap rest of the code in IIFE
(async () => {
  const module = await window.System.import("@internal/foo-service");

  // Use await keyword if FooService/doBar/doBar2 are async
  const fooService = await module.FooService;
  const doBar = await fooService;
  const doBar2 = await fooService;

  async function func1() {
    doBar();
  }

  async function func2() {
    doBar2();
  }
})();
```

Comment: Since it is a Vuex module I don't think that is possible :/