# Jest cannot read property 'import' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, mocking, systemjs

I have the following code to load a dependency asynchronously:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    System: System.Module
  }
}

const fooService = window.System.import('@internal/foo-service').then(module => module.FooService)
//                              ^ Jest trips up here

async function func1() {
  (await fooService).doBar()
  …
}

async function func2() {
  (await fooService).doBar2()
  …
}
```

This works fine thanks to [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65561311/7910454) but Jest is tripping up over `window.System.import` and gives me the error `Cannot read property 'import' of undefined`. How can I properly mock this?

Comment: instead of `Window` in `interface Window {
    System: System.Module
  }` it should be window i guess

Comment: @Sakshi Read the question again and you will realize that this proposal does not make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window property can be mocked like that:

```
import { System } from 'systemjs'

Object.defineProperty(window, 'System', { value: System })
```

For some reason I can't explain, this needs to happen before the import (!) of the component that is being tested.