# How to initialize private property of a class for a test

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, ecmascript-next, class-fields

I'm trying to write a test using JEST to a class I wrote with static properties that resembles the following:

```
class DataManager {
    static #data = null;

    static getData = () => {
        return this.#data;
    }

    static initializeData = async () => {
        await database(async (db) => {
            const data = getSomeDataFromDatabase() //just example
            this.#data = data;
        });
    }
}
```

Now, I want to make new implementation for my *initializeData* method, to returned some mocked data instead of going to the db, and then "getData" to see if I get the expected result. The problem is that my #data property is private and I don't want to expose it to the outside world. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: why are using `static`?

Comment: To complement @Tibebes.M: …and [why are you using `class`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572)?

Comment: Tibebes.M & @Bergi I don't use any framework that comes with dependency injection mechanism and I wanted to avoid spreading instances among different files. Also, I needed to have some in-memory data that could be shared across the app. Because all this functions work with the same data, I thought it would be a good practice to put it in one place and I thought that a class is an appropriate way to do it.

Comment: Put it one place, yes, but a simple module or object literal would've been enough. `class`es should be used when you want to instantiate multiple objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. **Private fields are really private**. If you want to mock them in a test, don't use private fields. Or the other way round: if they're private (an implementation detail), you shouldn't mock them.

You need to either mock the entire `DataManager` class and its public methods, or if you want to test the `DataManager` itself then you'd mock the `database` and `getSomeDataFromDatabase` functions that it calls.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I took your advice and it worked