# Call classes from strings names, in ES6 modules (commonjs) compiled by Webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, es6-modules

In a web project with TypeScript, using commonjs modules, compiled through Webpack (version 5), I need to call classes and methods dynamically from string variables containing their names.

I can separate those files that will be used "globally" through folders or with a different extension. As a last resort, I can even create an index file to manually include all the files that need to be accessed this way.

The problem is that:

- When I use `INCLUDE`, the Webpack makes the classes inaccessible.
- When I don't use `INCLUDE`, Webpack doesn't insert the classes in bundle.js

In this project the API return is processed by a module (ES6 / commonjs), and there will be times when the API will return which JavaScript class/method should be executed in the Browser. This way, the name of the class and the method will be known from variables of type string.

As an example, I have the following scenario:

- main.ts: entrypoint.
- MyModule.ts: module that makes AJAX calls, receives the return and calls the method returned by the API.
- MyGlobal.glob.ts: Class with an example of one of the methods that can be called by the `MyModule.ts` callback.

File `main.ts`:

```
import { MyModule } from './MyModule';

MyModule.callApi();
```

File `MyModule.ts`:

```
import { MyGlobal } from './MyGlobal.glob';

export class MyModule {
    public static callApi() {
        /**
         * This method makes an AJAX call 
         * and passes the return JSON to the callback
         */
        let my_return = {
            class: 'MyGlobal',
            method: 'bar',
        };
        this.callback(my_return);
    }

    public static callback(my_return: any) {
        classes[my_return.class][my_return.method]();   
    }
}
```

File `MyGlobal.glob.ts`:

```
export class MyGlobal {
    public static foo() {
        return 1;
    }

    public static bar() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

When running the code above, I get the following error:

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: MyGlobal is not defined
>     at eval (eval at callback (main.js:1), <anonymous>:1:1)
>     at Function.callback (main.js:1)
>     at Function.callApi (main.js:1)
>     at main.js:1
>     at main.js:1
```

How to call these methods, from strings, when, after compiled by the webpack, these "original class/method names" are inaccessible?

I greatly appreciate any help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, you should build an index file that creates the `Map` in which the classes can be looked up by their name.

Comment: "*using commonjs modules*" - then why is your question tagged [[tag:es6-modules]]?

Comment: I need to call this classes dynamically from string variables containing their names. How to do it inside a commonjs module? Thanks.

Comment: In this project the API return is processed by a module (ES6 / commonjs), and there will be times when the API will return which JavaScript class/method should be executed in the Browser. This way, the name of the class and the method will be known from variables of type string.

How to call these methods, from strings, when, after compiled by the webpack, these "original class/method names" are inaccessible?

Comment: Commonjs already support what you are trying to do. I often dynamically require modules using `require()` because unlike es6 `import` the commonjs `require()` is just a regular function. So you can pass a variable to it. Now your problem is making sure Webpack compiles those modules and not remove them by tree-shaking.

Comment: Do not use `eval`. Use `classes[my_return.class][my_return.method]()`, with a lookup map `classes`.

Comment: Btw, [do not use `class`es that consist of onyl `static` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572)! What you want is an object literal.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks for the help. I had the same error with "classes[my_return.class][my_return.method](); ", and the static methods is only an example. It can be static ou dynamic. The center question still the same: how call it from string variables on javascript compiled by Webpack.

Comment: @AllanAndrade How did you create the `classes` object?