# Typescript recursively infer object values

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference, union-types

Let's say I have this AnalyticsService class

```js
export class AnalyticsService {
  static sendAnalytics(eventName: string) {
    console.log(eventName);
    // logic here...
  }

  static EVENTS = {
    Header: {
      LogoClicked: "Header: Logo Clicked",
    },
    UserMenu: {
      LoginButtonClicked: "User Menu: Login Button Clicked",
      LogoutButtonClicked: "User Menu: Logout Button Clicked",
    }
  };
}
```

And I use this class to send analytics like:

```js
AnalyticsService.sendAnalytics(AnalyticsService.EVENTS.Header.LogoClicked)
```

I want to extract all values of `EVENTS` to a union type
to make sure that `sendAnalytics` function gets only existing event names

for example, the results here should be:
`"Header: Logo Clicked" | "User Menu: Login Button Clicked" | "User Menu: Logout Button Clicked"`

Is it even possible with typescript?

If it is, is it going to significantly reduce the typescript performance when it's a pretty big object?

**Edit**: just to clarify the `EVENTS` object can be really nested (I gave a tiny example just for simplicity )

Comment: Why not use an `enum`?

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't use a `class` if it contains only `static` members.

Comment: @Bergi I took it from a real class so in reality we have tons of things there. also, can you explain why I shouldn't use class with static members? it's convenient

Comment: It's less convenient, less efficient, and less concise than [just using an object literal or named module exports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi I don't use enum because enum is flat and we want the EVENTS to be very nested

Comment: The `eventName: string` parameter to your function is very flat.

Comment: @Bergi right, but when I pass the string to the function I pass it like `AnalyticsService.EVENTS.Header.LogoClicked` not like "someEvent"

Comment: `sendAnalytics` doesn't know that, and TypeScript won't check for it. You might as well pass a string literal, it works the same - and you ask for that union type so that only the right strings are passed, right? Because if you already had a rule that ensures you pass `EVENTS.Header.LogoClicked`, you wouldn't need this type check at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do to correctly type `sendAnalytics`:

```
type Keys = typeof AnalyticsService.EVENTS[keyof typeof AnalyticsService.EVENTS]

type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type FlattenedEvents = UnionToIntersection<Keys>;

type EventNames = FlattenedEvents[keyof FlattenedEvents];

export class AnalyticsService {
  static sendAnalytics(eventName: EventNames) {
    console.log(eventName);
    // logic here...
  }

  static EVENTS = {
    Header: {
      LogoClicked: "Header: Logo Clicked",
    },
    UserMenu: {
      LoginButtonClicked: "User Menu: Login Button Clicked",
      LogoutButtonClicked: "User Menu: Logout Button Clicked",
    }
  } as const;
}

AnalyticsService.sendAnalytics(AnalyticsService.EVENTS.Header.LogoClicked); // OK
AnalyticsService.sendAnalytics('test'); // KO
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4qkgewGZQIIDsBDAGxGAEsBjBAZQgCcA3KiAOgFEA1dgOQBUaAbQDW8bGnARxBEmSq0GzSmy68BAXQBQm9NACq%20chnx8MASXzAGCCJQrGAPHoB8KTVCgAKPVAgAPK3wAEyRCfBAoAH4vYQAuKD0AShRXRgxyIKh4-AhGBmT-QJCvTziocnwsBigzZORU9KDk6LMsqBy8%20m1dKAAxYkJgQIgg9jzLJFQDIxNzS2tbe3wHOERnAG5uySgxiEseQgBbCEm%20gaG9kd2JkTEcfsHh0fHgBHVNzX8wDHpgKEoBggkDJSBRqHQmCwoABvdxQBDAQZUeF7IIguTUTy5PbAA7HeLXXFHE7JWEeDyUYwIDDENjEDAAcyxLzxEESm3JUAA9FyoPSGciABYMNisVhwgC%202g8CKRlB23H4NBQMLhHgAEhBCEEGPEyZyoAAZRkYADCxCooiC8QARJrtbqjSaoObLSMbQAaNVQCVezl6Gz0ACyewArnrvR5jQL8AAhUNDYyuyhW20B6oh-Dhp0xqDxxP4F0WlPuv0G6MYBP54BJ4upqA29P0KCZ7MVhN5hM1wvJq2e71SjwSqCEJCU-AIzZSzTosEKSHKVg2YKz%20SeVfgxQsDiKgSse06%20isCu9kbs7m8gDyMBnRFB8ghSjYy7Rd4xCE8AHIrAjP%20eebAl5AA)

Comment: It's nice, but my object can be really nested, and I don't want to add `keyof typeof AnalyticsService.EVENTS.SOMETHING_ELSE` every time I add something. (I don't want to hard-coded the Keys)