# Nextjs: static class / use function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to create tools class/function in nextjs

I have 2 ways for this.

> With static class:

```
class Tools {
    static titleCase(value: string) {
        return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }
}

export default Tools
```

> With use function:

```
export default function Tools(){
    function titleCase(value: string) {
        return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }

    return { titleCase }
}
```

And here is my question:

1- Which is better?

2- What is difference between these?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't tack on tags. See [ask].

Comment: Your second snippet is not static at all. It requires a call like `const t = Tools(); t.titleCase(…)` whereas for your first it's just `Tools.titleCase(…)`

Comment: See also [ES6 modules: Export single class of static methods OR multiple individual methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

Neither. The better solution for static utility functions is to use named exports:

```
// tool.js:
export function titleCase(value: string) {
    return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Shorter, no unnecessary intermediate objects, and good for tree-shaking.