# ES6 Module: Shared class best approach

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Considering the following where both the importer and a module use another module:

`main.js`:

```js
export class Main {
  static func1() {}
  static func2() {}
  static func3() {}
}
```

`one.js`:

```js
import { Main } from './main.js';
export { one };
// one also uses some methods in Main.
```

`background.js`:

```js
import { Main } from './main.js';
import { one } from './one.js';
```

Would it be better if the process is done as a re-export?

`main.js`:

```js
export class Main {
  static func1() {}
  static func2() {}
  static func3() {}
}
```

`one.js`:

```js
import { Main } from './main.js';
export { one, Main };
// one also uses some methods in Main.
```

`background.js`:

```js
import { one, Main } from './one.js';
```

First one is easier to read. Are there any performance concerns?

Comment: I doubt there’s any significant performance concerns given that a module is only executed once when imported anywhere in the module tree.

Comment: have you looked at mixins?

Comment: don't do the re-export. that's gonna be so confusing when things get more complicated. then again i would probably not use static methods either. instead I would give Main regular methods, instantiate the Main class, then pass the Main object into the constructor of the other two classes, to give them a reference to save and use when needed. but this is more of an opinion.

Comment: @chovy not really..any examples?

Comment: @dqhendricks Wouldn't that instantiate the Main class twice? Any examples?

Comment: mixins are sort of how you derivce a class that has functions from other classes.

Comment: Doing both `export { Main }` and `export class Main {…}` in the same module is an error.

Comment: [Don't export a `class` with only static methods!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29895235/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi .. oops, right.... typo corrected. AFA `static` export, why is that? Of course this is a simplified example.

Comment: @erosman Simplified or not, the rule of thumb is: if you never instantiate multiple `new Main` (or at least, one), then you shouldn't be using `class` syntax

Comment: @Bergi Do you mean to use an object instead of `class`?

Comment: @erosman Yes, or even better, just multiple named exports. See the link above.

Comment: @erosman no, you instantiate the main class once, then pass that one object into both classes that need to use it.

Comment: @dqhendricks Why would you use a `class` if you instantiate it only once? Use a simple object then.

Comment: @Bergi In a Utility type `class` with 10+ `static` methods, export/importing one by one could be cumbersome. Furthermore, it appears that a single class/object saved to a single memory location performs better than multiple variables saved to multiple locations in a browser extension environment.

Comment: @erosman Exporting function declarations isn't really cumbersome, but still, what I'm arguing is that you should just use an object literal instead of a `class` if you need only a single instance (or none at all), that's even more memory-efficient.

Comment: @Bergi I am going to start a new topic for proper discussion.

Answer (score 0):

ES modules only evaluate once, no matter how many times they are imported (and don't ever evaluate if they are not imported anywhere). You may check that by adding `console.log` into the outer scope of the module.

In your case, using `import { Main } from './one.js';` will evaluate `one.js` module on top of `main.js`, but since your already import `one` from `one.js` that makes no difference at all.

Comment: Small caveat that feels worth mentioning: modules are identified by URL, so the same module can be imported twice (and execute twice) if the URL is different. They’re also identified by MIME type, at least in upcoming JS engines.