# Typescript/JavaScript Service pattern - singleton vs. creating new instance

Tags: javascript, typescript, singleton

I structure my TypeScript code using services, which are essentially classes housing multiple functions for code organization. Here's an example:

```
export class MyService {
  public doSomething(){
    //business logic...
  }
//other methods...
}
```

However, I'm considering using the singleton pattern for these classes:

```
export class MyServiceSingleton {
  private static instance: MyServiceSingleton | null = null;

  private constructor() { }

  static getInstance(): MyServiceSingleton {
    if (!MyServiceSingleton.instance) {
      MyServiceSingleton.instance = new MyServiceSingleton();
    }
    return MyServiceSingleton.instance;
  }
  
  // Other methods...
}
```

I don't require data sharing between functions or globally. Would converting all services to a singleton affect performance, especially for frequently used services?
I would appreciate any insights or experiences you may have on this matter.

Comment: That's the wrong question for multiple reasons. Performance shouldn't be a main concern.  See [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). But moreover, "I have a class, which *doesn't work as a class*, I now want to encode that by a singleton" is also the wrong tool for the already wrong job. Use modules with exported functions. Done. You won't have instances to care about. It also more correctly models what you have, whereas OOP is flawed in this regard - it *cannot* accurately model functions.

Comment: "*classes housing multiple functions for code organization*" - [don't use `class`es for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29895235/1048572). JS has modules for code organisation.